# transfer netbeans made component to lwuit's "Resource Editor"

Tags: netbeans, java-me, resources, editor, lwuit

I tried to use "table" `Component` in a `Form` with "Resource Editor" in lwuit, but I could not add/edit the rows items. so I end up with this question:

Is it possible to create/edit the table component in the generated "StateMachine" class in Netbeans and see the result in "Resource Editor"?

And if it's not possible, how can I hack the .res file in order to make the "table" as it should be?

Comment: I think that is not possible. @ShaiAlmog should know the answer

Answer (score 1):

There is support for live embedding in the resource editor but its deprecated and obtuse.

I suggest you just add a label where you want the custom component to be, give it a unique name and override the method `createComponentInstance` which is invoked internally with the name of the label (name it something unique).

You can then just return the instance of your custom made component and it will appear where the label is in the GUI builder.